# Apple Watch notifications over WiFi

Tags: iphone, wifi, bluetooth, notifications, apple-watch

First days after I've bought my Apple Watch, keeping my iPhone with Bluetooth turned off and WiFi on (so with Apple Watch connected "to the cloud") my Watch was able to receive iPhone's notifications as it was connected with bluetooth.

Now this "feature" died, so if I have my iPhone with Bluetooth turned off and WiFi on and my Apple Watch connected to the cloud, Watch don't receive any notifications; is there a way to restore this "feature"?

EDIT: This morning works!! Here's an example:

[image]
iPhone connected only to WiFi and W connected to the Cloud.

[image]
........ W Receives iPhone's notification!

Comment: I tried asking to Apple support but they say that notifications should work only with bluetooth, so if they worked over WiFi for a short period was just an unexpected extra!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution which (more or less) works!
Every night, before going to sleep I turn off my W (I've never understood what's the correct mode to keep it during the night!) and in plane mode my iPhone. When I wake up I turn on my Watch and plug the phone to WiFi until I go out. To receive iPhone's notifications in this condition I have to turn on bluetooth until phone and watch plug, then turning off bluetooth, Watch will keep receiving notifications (sometimes it doesn't work at first time!). So, probably, everytime Watch turns on needs to "recognise" his phone, then it can keep finding them even over WiFi.

EDIT: With Watch OS3, bluetooth pairing seems not necessary: just turning the Watch on, on the same WiFi of the iPhone, it receive phone's notifications!

Answer (score 0):

Apple Watch connects to Wi-Fi networks it has connected whilst being linked via Bluetooth with your iPhone. See: [About Bluetooth and Wi-Fi on Apple Watch](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204562)

So, let's say you forget your phone at home but you're wearing your watch at work. Your watch will recognize the wifi network and still give you your notifications over Wi-Fi.

You might also need to mirror notifications. See: [About notifications on your Apple Watch](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204791)

Comment: ...and how this should solve my problem?

Answer (score -1):

Watch only produces notifications with a Bluetooth connection to your iPhone.